# Function Pointer in Struct

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct

How do you use Function Pointer in Struct? 
Specifically, given the following example, the program compiles but crash on run-time:

In a header file

```
 #ifndef __FUNCTION_IN_STRUCT_H_
 #define __FUNCTION_IN_STRUCT_H_


struct functionDaemon {
     int id;
     //double (*funcp); // function pointer
     double  (*fp)(double);      // Function pointer
 };

 // #define NULL 'V'

 #endif /* _FUNCTION_IN_STRUCT_H_ */
```

In the C file:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "function_in_struct.h"

extern struct functionDaemon *ftnAgent;

void do_compute_sum (void) {

     void* agent;
    // struct functionDaemon *ftnAgent = (struct functionDaemon *) agent;
    struct functionDaemon *ftnAgent;

    double  sum;

    // Use 'sin()' as the pointed-to function
    ftnAgent->fp = sin;
    sum = compute_sum(ftnAgent->fp, 0.0, 1.0);
    printf("sum(sin): %f\n", sum);

}
```

Please advise me.

Comment: You're using a [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: Where is compute_sum defined? Also you do not allocate any memory for `ftnAgent`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
struct functionDaemon *ftnAgent;

double  sum;

// Use 'sin()' as the pointed-to function
ftnAgent->fp = sin;
```

Your `ftnAgent` is just a non-initialized pointer.

```
struct functionDaemon ftnAgent;

double  sum;

// Use 'sin()' as the pointed-to function
ftnAgent.fp = sin;
sum = compute_sum(ftnAgent.fp, 0.0, 1.0);
```

Here is a working example:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>


struct functionDaemon {
     int id;
     //double (*funcp); // function pointer
     double  (*fp)(double);      // Function pointer
 };


int main()
{
        struct functionDaemon f;
        f.fp = sin;

        printf("%f\n", (f.fp)(10));

        return 0;
}
```

**Edit**

As you have this:

```
extern struct functionDaemon *ftnAgent;
```

I assume `ftnAgent` is instantiated somewhere else. In this case, you don't need `struct functionDaemon *ftnAgent;` inside `do_compute_sum` as it will hide the already declared `ftnAgent` struct, so you will access the wrong (uninitialized) variable.

Comment: Based on `extern struct functionDaemon *ftnAgent;`, I'd assume the OP was trying to define this somewhere else, but then hiding it with the local variable.